# How to hide columns in Google Sheet with checkboxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Could someone help me figure out how to be able to hide/unhide columns by using a checkbox in Google Sheets.

For example, the checkbox is located in `N4` and I want to hide/unhide column from `O` to `R`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use an `onEdit()` trigger.*

#### Code Sample:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != "N4") return;

  if (e.value == "TRUE") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().hideColumns(15, 4);
  }
  else if (e.value == "FALSE") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().showColumns(15, 4);
  }
}
```

**Function run-down:**

- Checks to see if the edited cell was `N4`

  - If it isn't `N4`, do nothing.
- If it *is* `N4`, then:

  - If the value is true (checkbox is checked), then hide columns `O` to `R`.
  - If the value is false (checkbox is unchecked), then show columns `O` to `R`.

If you wish it to be the other way around then swap the `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` values in the conditional.

#### References:

- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Simple Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Class Sheet: `hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)
- [Class Sheet: `showColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)